# Alguna información para poder inciar sesión con diferentes tipos de usuarios en una app android studio

Tags: php, java, android-studio

Estoy creando un proyecto es muy complejo poco a poco le ido avanzando parte de la universidad, tengo un formulario de inicio de sesión, el cual si no se tiene una cuenta el usuario tipo invitado podrá registrarse y acceder con su correo y contraseña que genere,lo que quiero es restringir ciertos `activitys`o `fragment` ya que son registros de productos que solo podrán ver los administradores, lo que he pensado es crear un correos de tipo administrador y su contraseña solo es cuestión de darles privilegios de acceso, pero no he logrado llevarlo a cabo en en el activity de login, hasta el momento se puede acceder pero no esta restringido nada, estoy trabajando con PHP, Mysql y volley.

**login.php**

```
<?php

 include("conexion.php");
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $pass = $_POST["pass"];

 if (empty($email) && empty($pass)) {
 echo "0";

 } else {

 $statement=$mysql->prepare('SELECT * FROM t_usuario WHERE email=?');
 $statement->bind_param("s",$email);

  if ($statement->execute()) {
    
    $results = $statement->get_result();
    if ($results->num_rows ==1) {
        $pass_hash = $results->fetch_assoc();
        if (password_verify($pass, $pass_hash["pass"])) {
            
            echo "1";
        }else {
            echo "2";
        }
    } else {
        echo "3";
    }

  } else {
    echo "4";
 }
}
 $mysql->close();
?>
```

Comment: Deberias tener un campo que diga que tipo de usuario es.. busca sobre perfiles de usuarios...

Comment: @gbianchi tendría que hacer otro formulario donde tenga el tipo de usuario o perfil , ya que el que tengo solo es para registro de usuarios invitados que ellos mismos se registran en la app que contiene el campo(nombreCompleto, nombreUsuario,email, pass).

Comment: Entonces es solo mas facil.. esos usuarios ya sabes que tienen el perfil invitados.. los administradores se registran por otro lado, o a mano...